# Postgres Data type conversion

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this dataset that's in a SQL format.  However the DATE type needs to be converted into a different format because I get the following error

```
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 1
INSERT 0 1
INSERT 0 1
INSERT 0 1
ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "28-10-96"
LINE 58: ...040','2','10','','P13-00206','','','','','1-3-95','28-10-96'...
                                                          ^
HINT:  Perhaps you need a different "datestyle" setting.
```

I've definitely read the documentation on date format
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html

But my question is how do I convert all of the dates in a proper format without going through all the 500 or so data rows and making sure each one is correct before inserting into a DB.  Backend is handle by rails, but I figured going through SQL to cleaning it up will be best here.

I have a `CREATE TABLE` statement above this dataset, and mind you the data set was given to be via a DBF converter/external source

Here's part of my dataset

```
INSERT INTO winery_attributes
  (ID,NAME,STATUS,BLDSZ_ORIG,BLDSZ_CURR,HAS_CAVE,CAVESIZE,PROD_ORIG,PROD_CURR,TOUR_TASTG,VISIT_DAY,VISIT_WEEK,VISIT_YR,VISIT_MKTG,VISIT_NMEV,VISIT_ALL,EMPLYEENUM,PARKINGNUM,WDO,LAST_UP,IN_CITYBDY,IN_AIASP,NOTES,SMLWNRYEXM,APPRV_DATE,ESTAB_DATE,TOTAL_SIZE,SUBJ_TO_75,GPY_AT_75,AVA,SUP_DIST)
VALUES
  (1,'ACACIA WINERY','PROD','8000','34436','','0','50000','250000','APPT','75','525','27375','3612','63','30987','22','97','x','001_02169-MOD_AcaciaWinery','','','','','1-11-79','1-9-82','34436','x','125000','Los Carneros','1');

INSERT INTO winery_attributes
  (ID,NAME,STATUS,BLDSZ_ORIG,BLDSZ_CURR,HAS_CAVE,CAVESIZE,PROD_ORIG,PROD_CURR,TOUR_TASTG,VISIT_DAY,VISIT_WEEK,VISIT_YR,VISIT_MKTG,VISIT_NMEV,VISIT_ALL,EMPLYEENUM,PARKINGNUM,WDO,LAST_UP,IN_CITYBDY,IN_AIASP,NOTES,SMLWNRYEXM,APPRV_DATE,ESTAB_DATE,TOTAL_SIZE,SUBJ_TO_75,GPY_AT_75,AVA,SUP_DIST)
VALUES
  ('2','AETNA SPRING CELLARS','PROD','2500','2500','','0','2000','20000','TST APPT','0','3','156','0','0','156','1','10','x','','','','','x','1-4-86','1-6-86','2500','','0','Napa Valley','3');

INSERT INTO winery_attributes
  (ID,NAME,STATUS,BLDSZ_ORIG,BLDSZ_CURR,HAS_CAVE,CAVESIZE,PROD_ORIG,PROD_CURR,TOUR_TASTG,VISIT_DAY,VISIT_WEEK,VISIT_YR,VISIT_MKTG,VISIT_NMEV,VISIT_ALL,EMPLYEENUM,PARKINGNUM,WDO,LAST_UP,IN_CITYBDY,IN_AIASP,NOTES,SMLWNRYEXM,APPRV_DATE,ESTAB_DATE,TOTAL_SIZE,SUBJ_TO_75,GPY_AT_75,AVA,SUP_DIST)
VALUES
  ('3','ALTA VINEYARD CELLAR','PROD','480','480','','0','5000','5000','NO','0','4','208','0','0','208','4','6','x','003_U-387879','','','','','2-5-79','1-9-80','480','','0','Diamond Mountain District','3');

INSERT INTO winery_attributes
  (ID,NAME,STATUS,BLDSZ_ORIG,BLDSZ_CURR,HAS_CAVE,CAVESIZE,PROD_ORIG,PROD_CURR,TOUR_TASTG,VISIT_DAY,VISIT_WEEK,VISIT_YR,VISIT_MKTG,VISIT_NMEV,VISIT_ALL,EMPLYEENUM,PARKINGNUM,WDO,LAST_UP,IN_CITYBDY,IN_AIASP,NOTES,SMLWNRYEXM,APPRV_DATE,ESTAB_DATE,TOTAL_SIZE,SUBJ_TO_75,GPY_AT_75,AVA,SUP_DIST)
VALUES
  ('4','BLACK STALLION','PROD','43600','43600','','0','100000','100000','PUB','50','350','18200','0','0','18200','2','45','x','P13-00391','','','','','1-5-80','1-9-85','43600','','0','Oak Knoll District of Napa Valley','3');

INSERT INTO winery_attributes
  (ID,NAME,STATUS,BLDSZ_ORIG,BLDSZ_CURR,HAS_CAVE,CAVESIZE,PROD_ORIG,PROD_CURR,TOUR_TASTG,VISIT_DAY,VISIT_WEEK,VISIT_YR,VISIT_MKTG,VISIT_NMEV,VISIT_ALL,EMPLYEENUM,PARKINGNUM,WDO,LAST_UP,IN_CITYBDY,IN_AIASP,NOTES,SMLWNRYEXM,APPRV_DATE,ESTAB_DATE,TOTAL_SIZE,SUBJ_TO_75,GPY_AT_75,AVA,SUP_DIST)
VALUES
  ('5','ALTAMURA WINERY','PROD','11800','11800','x','3115','50000','50000','APPT','0','20','1040','0','0','1040','2','10','','P13-00206','','','','','1-3-95','28-10-96','14915','x','50000','Napa Valley','4');
```

Comment: you get the problem with "28-10-96". May be you have an English configuratión (MM-DD-YY)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dates in your data set are in the form of a string. Since they are not in the default `datestyle` (which is YYYY-MM-DD) you should explicitly convert them to a `date` as follows:

```
to_date('1-5-80', 'DD-MM-YY')
```

If you store the data in a `timestamp` instead, use

```
to_timestamp('1-5-80', 'DD-MM-YY')
```

If you are given the data set in the form of the `INSERT` statements that you show, then first load all the data as simple strings into `varchar` columns, then add `date` columns and do an `UPDATE` (and similarly for `integer` and `boolean` columns):

```
UPDATE my_table
SET estab = to_date(ESTAB_DATE, 'DD-MM-YY'), -- column estab of type date
    apprv = to_date(APPRV_DATE, 'DD-MM-YY'), -- etc
    ...
```

When the update is done you can `ALTER TABLE` to drop the text columns with dates (integers, booleans).

Comment: Ahh okay, that was my second guess, was to insert them all as strings and then update later using the to_date function.  I thought there would be a more direct way to do it.  In my CREATE TABLE statement I set the type as DATE, but I 'll just CHAR as you suggested to get them loaded.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can also do the conversion in `ALTER TABLE` with `USING to_date(textfield, 'DD-MM-YY')` so you don't have to first create temp columns and then drop the previous ones.